# Maintaining Polynomial Irreducibility

Tags: abstract-algebra, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Is there a polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree $d$, such that on changing any $O(\sqrt{d})$ of its coefficients, it still remains irreducible?

By changing, I mean I have no control over what those changed $O(\sqrt{d})$ coefficients would be. Now of course, if the constant term becomes zero after change, then we will have $x$ as a factor, and hence reducible. Say, I am okay with such changes. In other words, is there an explicit polynomial $f(x)$ such that after change, it becomes $x^i.f^{\prime}(x)$, where $f^{\prime}(x)$ is irreducible and $i \geq 0$.

I was thinking to start with a polynomial with different prime numbers as coefficients that satisfies Eisenstein's or some irreducibility criterion, so that it becomes easier to argue irreducibility after change also, by looking at remaining $d-O(\sqrt{d})$ coefficients. But, I was unable to find any irreducibility criterion that is compatible with change of coefficients.

Any positive or negative answer to the above question is appreciated, in fact, for $f \in \mathbb{F}[x]$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is any field. I also don't mind if there is a result which is not precisely $O(\sqrt{d})$ coefficients but is anything of this flavor that after perturbation of some of its coefficients, the polynomial remains irreducible.

Comment: why do you think this might be possible? Do you have examples that almost satisfy?

Comment: @WillJagy Not really. The density of irreducible polynomials is high, so I was wondering if such a 'resistant' irreducible polynomial exists. I want to use the above property to prove some other research problem, I have been working on. So, I am fine with a yes or no answer or any sort of intuition for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $d$ be an integer with $d\ge 2$, and let $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be irreducible with $\deg(f)=d$.

Write $f={\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^d a_kx^k}}$.

Let $b_1=a_1-f(1)$, and let $g$ be the polynomial obtained from $f$ by replacing the term $a_1x$ by the term $b_1x$.

Then $g=f+(b_1x-a_1x)$, hence $g(1)=f(1)+(b_1-a_1)=0$, so $g$ is reducible.

Note that in the transition from $f$ to $g$, only one coefficient was changed.

Comment: Red alarm started ringing when I could not answer @WillJaggy's question and could not find an example resistant to even one coefficient change. You just nailed the coffin! I will try to put more thought or try more examples next time before posting. Thanks!

Comment: @PranavBisht  suggest learning some programming languages appropriate for testing of possible conjectures. For real number items, perhaps matlab. For number theory, python seems popular; it leads naturally to Sage. I use gp/Pari for various real number questions, although I still do not know how to implement loops in pari. I use C++ for number theory searches and sanity testing  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanity_check